# stop installation if detect process is running

Tags: process, advanced-installer

I want to check if a process is running before installing a new add-in using the advance installer. To make that, in custom Actions, I select detect process and put the process that I want to stop. With that I get AI_PROCESS_STATE Running or Stopped. But now I don't know what to do to stop the installation if it is Running or at least show a message telling that is necessary to close it before continue.

There are options like display message box but if I put them they always appear. I don't know how to make them appear only when AI_PROCESS_STATE has the value Running.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems here:

The general way to do this is to call a custom action Dll that looks for the process, and sets an installer property if the process is running, then you can fail the install with a type 19 custom action and your own error message. Running a process doesn't give you a good way to return a value into the install so you can show an error message.

However, getting the list of processes requires elevation, and by default you're not elevated at the start of the install.

Are you sure you're not inventing a problem? Why should the user shut down the process? The user-friendly approach is to register your add-in and tell the user they may need to restart the app before their new add-in will show up.

Comment: the problem is that sometimes even if you close powerpoint it still keeps on running in the background. So when I send updates to customers they install them but still are working with the old add-in. So I want to make sure that when they install a new add-in they are working with the new one.

Comment: IMO, if it were me, I'd say it's up to me when I decide to use the new add-in, and it's unfriendly to force the user to shut down PowerPoint before you'll even permit the installation to start. The fact that you need elevation to enumerate processes also requires the user to get admin privileges at some point. If you want your add-in available to limited users, install it for each user and don't require admin rights. I believe Office is user-based anyway, not system based.