# How to create custom action that will terminate MSI installation?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

All.

I'd like to ask on how I can create a custom action that will terminate the MSI installation if the queried process is running?

Thanks!

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197577/stop-installation-if-detect-process-is-running

Comment: Basically you need a custom launch condition, that prevents the MSI from starting if the EXE runs. Don't work with IS so I don't know its capabilities in detecting if a EXE runs, with other tools is quite simple

Comment: I'm using IS. http://www.itninja.com/question/how-to-create-custom-action-that-will-terminate-msi-installation